# Auto create node reference in Drupal 7

Tags: nodes, users, entities

I have made a new content type called wall and used user reference on it. Is there a way to auto create node whenever a new user is registered? I found the [Autocreate Node Reference](http://drupal.org/project/autocreate) module but it doesn't have version 7 so I'm looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good example where [Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules) can help you. I myself probably just write some custom code, since that's easy for me. But if you don't want to/can't do this, Rules can help you.

You can setup a rule, that is executed when a new user is created that will create a content of the chosen type. With tokens you can populate the values needed.

Using Rules can be a bit complex, but it's very powerful.

Comment: Ok I got rules to create node everytime a user is registered but I don't know how to make it enter a value in the reference field with rules

Comment: @Ruriko Like I said, You need to set the value to the field you created with tokens (the id of the user created)

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to write your own module. You can use [hook_user_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7) to perform actions when a new user is added.

Then use [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save/7) to insert a new node

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Node Reference Create](http://drupal.org/project/noderefcreate) module for Drupal 7 (and 6) which does this. But probably you need to write a custom module to create a node after a user has registered.

Comment: I'm not a programmer so any other alternatives?

Comment: Does it not work with this module?

Comment: it doesn't have user reference but only node reference

Comment: Probably you try to describe again what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what googletorp mentioned, do you think the link below would be of any help?

http://drupal.org/node/630814